# CSS transform works only in Chrome?

Tags: css, css-transforms, perspective

This code allows a hover effect `transform: rotateX(-20deg);` to work perfectly on Chrome, but the transform-style is flat on Edge and Firefox. Applying `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the nested elements breaks it everywhere, including Chrome. (Furthermore, the mouse position for the hover effect on Edge is *way* off.) What's going on here?

```css
#perspective {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 perspective: 2500px;
}

#grid {
 padding-right: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 1000px;
 column-count: 4;
 column-gap: 0;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 transform-origin: top right;
 padding-left: 15px;
 transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(-40deg);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 z-index: 1;
}

#grid a {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  /*this breaks it.
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  */
}

#grid .brick {
  display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 0 #999;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 transform-origin: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#grid a:hover .brick, #grid .brick:hover {
 transform: rotateX(-20deg);
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: -5px 2px 0 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective">
  <div id="grid">
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
    <a href="#test"><span class="brick"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, transform is kinds special in css... you will need to define it a couple of times to make it work in other browsers too:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin Unfortunately, adding browser alternative prefixes doesn't help here. Transform is natively supported in both Firefox and Edge at this point. You can also see that the transforms themselves are actually applying, but they are collapsed into the plane of the grid. Thanks though!

Comment: Does anyone at least have a suggestion about where to look into this myself?